# Regex for selecting a phrase starting with tokens containing digits

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, python-re

I have texts such as this one:

```
text = 'this is a sentence, it has 1 number in it, and another one 123 here. we want to select n8m3r1c-aa words and phrases - until the punctuation. this is some phr4se!1 with text.'
```

My goal is to select snippets, starting with any token/word that has a digit in it and a space before. Selection should happen until the next punctuation that is found but not up to punctuation within the token.

Expected output:

```
1 number in it
123 here
n8m3r1c-aa words and phrases
phr4se!1 with text
```

My current approach:

```
re.findall(r'\s(\d.+?)[.,!]', text)
```

But this only finds:

```
1 number in it
123 here
```

I'm a bit stuck starting the selection at tokens that not only start with a digit but also contain a digit. I appreciate any help and suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you tried gets 2 matches because it starts with `\s(\d` so that means it should start with a digit.

You could use `[^\s\d]*\d\S*` to match optional whitespace chars until the first digit and optionally match following non whitespace chars.

```
(?<!\S)[^\s\d]*\d\S*.*?(?=[.,!-])
```

*In parts*

- `(?<!\S)` Assert whitespace boundary to the left
- `[^\s\d]*` Match any char except a whitespace char or digit
- `\d` Match a digit
- `\S*` Match 0+ times a non whitespace char (the rest of the "word")
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline as least as possible
- `(?=[.,!-])` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is any of the listed chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UBSdyc/1)

If there should be a whitespace char at the start, you could also use a capturing group and match what precedes and follows:

```
\s([^\s\d]*\d\S*.*?)[.,!-]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HFdB1o/1)